# Transformation Matrix Multiplication by matrix type, C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, matrix, multiplication

Theoretically, let us assume we were to hard-code matrix multiplications for each different combination of 3D Homogeneous (4x4) transformation matrix (translation, rotation, scaling), and then for also each possible result of those (translation-rotation, translation-scaling, scaling-rotation)...

Suppose we were to handle matrix multiplication like that, a different function for each matrix type combination, where each matrix has an extra variable (type), and with the specific functions to use being determined at runtime (using a function pointer array).   If we applied this kind of matrix multiplication, could it theoretically be faster than doing basic, standard 4x4 homogeneous matrix multiplication (which is still admittedly faster than generic 4x4 matrix multiplication)?

I'm doing this right now, its kinda hellish to code.  I'm going to test it against standard matrix multiplication in the end, and compare results.  I just wanted to see what other people think the results might be.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better idea is to store only position and orientation of an object instead of the whole matrix. You only compute the matrix for rendering purpose, once after all transformations. The transformations are done by adding translations (for the position) and multiplying quaternions (for the orientation).

Comment: Yeah, thanks...
Been researching quaternions ever since this answer.  I had known a very tiny bit about them, before now.

Thank you!